# Bulk removal of unused categorised styles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, style, style-manager

I have a geopackage storing polygons for the geology of British Columbia. There is a widely adopted colour code/style for each unit and the geopackage contains the correct colour style. There are several hundred different units. I have subsetted the geopackage to a much smaller area of interest and I would like to delete the now unused styles. There are too many to delete manually so I have been searching for a fast way to do this.

In the print composer, it's easy to reduce the legend down to show only the styles that are within the map.

In the image below, you can see there are hundreds of styles, yet there are only 5 styles that are still relevant.

[image: example of lots of styles]

Comment: You want to remove the styles with no corresponding polygons (0 count)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PyQGIS.

I have a layer named `mylayer` with 11 symbol categories, symbolised by an integer field named `kkod`.

I only have `kkod` values of 611, 901, 911 in my layer so I want to drop all other categories.

Change "mylayer" and "kkod" below to match your data:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("mylayer")[0]
categoryfield = "kkod" #The field you are using to style by

values_in_layer = list({f[categoryfield] for f in layer.getFeatures()}) #Find all kkod values in my layer
#[611, 901, 911] I have only these three values, 
#  so I want to remove all other symbolised values

oldrend = layer.renderer() #Fetch the renderer object from the layer
oldcategories = oldrend.categories() #Find its categories
#[<QgsRendererCategory: 302 (302)>, <QgsRendererCategory: 303 (303)>, ... ]

newrend = oldrend.clone() #Create a new renderer by copying the old
newrend.deleteAllCategories() #Delete all old categories

for cat in oldcategories: #For each old symbol category
    if cat.value() in values_in_layer: #If the value of it exists in the layer values
        newrend.addCategory(cat) #Add it to the new renderer

layer.setRenderer(newrend)
```

[image]